# xslt date format change (dd-mmm-yyyy)

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am using the below code to show the current date in xslt program.It's working fine With the date format yyyy-mm-dd. But i need the format dd-mmm-yyyy. Please help me to do this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:cs="urn:cs"
>

          <xsl:value-of select="cs:datenow()"></xsl:value-of>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0 so I would expect you to simply get the current date with the `current-date` function http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-date and to format it with the XSLT 2.0 function `format-date` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date.
So basically `format-date(current-date(), '[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]')` gives a format like `11-JUL-2013`. Depending on your needs (I am not sure what the format `mmm` stands for, as most date formatting routines define their own patterns) you need to adapt the "picture string" argument of `format-date`, see the documentation I linked to.