# Convert date format to Mmm DD, YYYY in xslt

Tags: date, xslt

I have date in format 2009-02-07T15:23:00Z which needs to be converted to the format Mmm DD, YYYY in xslt.

How to achieve this? I have tried using `<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime()"/>`
But not getting any output may be due to some mistake which i am not bake to figure it out.

Please let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xslt date format change (dd-mmm-yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588060/xslt-date-format-change-dd-mmm-yyyy)

Comment: Please share the XSLT that you have tried. Depending on the XSLT version, the functions to convert date will differ.

Comment: xslt version is 1.0

Comment: The format-dateTime() function requires XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you will have to use substring functions. For example, `substring(date, 9, 2)` will get the DD. For the month, you will have to combine this with an `xsl:choose` to get the text for Mmm

Answer (score 0):

Worked using xsl:choose and substring(date, 9, 2).